# Layout as background for Panorama

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to set a background for my Panorama on Windows Phone platform. Background should be a separate layout or UI element, not static JPEG or PNG image. How can i do that?
Thanks.

Comment: You can not do that, it must be a image!

Answer (score 4):

So this actually is possible by overriding the panorama's Panning Layers (the control's secret sauce to the parallax effect):

```
<phone:Panorama>
    <phone:Panorama.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:Panorama">
            <Grid x:Name="TemplateGrid"
                  Background="Transparent"
                  Loaded="TemplateGrid_OnLoaded">
                  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                      <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                  <controlsPrimitives:PanningBackgroundLayer                       
                                 x:Name="BackgroundLayer"
                                 Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                      <!-- Whatever UI elements you like -->                          
                  </controlsPrimitives:PanningBackgroundLayer>
                  <controlsPrimitives:PanningTitleLayer x:Name="TitleLayer"
                                 Grid.Row="0"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                 CacheMode="BitmapCache"
                                 Content="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                                 ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}"/>
                  <controlsPrimitives:PanningLayer x:Name="ItemsLayer"
                                 Grid.Row="1"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                      <ItemsPresenter x:Name="items" />
                  </controlsPrimitives:PanningLayer>
              </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </phone:Panorama.Template>
</Panorama>
```

I would recommend you exercise caution with what you put in the Background Layer.  Shapes and images are fine, but buttons and other such input controls will be able to accept clicks and taps and that would be strange for the user.